# Maven-compiler-version for Amazon Corretto

Tags: aws, jdk

we are migrating our project from JDK1.8 to Amazon Corretto 8 version.
wondering which version should i need to mention in the maven-compiler-plugin in pom.xml.

This is the existing pom setup for Jdk1.8

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for putting up the question. We generate the war on local and deploy the same on server which was having legacy java version 6. Had the same doubt while migrating this legacy application from Oracle JAVA 6 to Amazon Corretto 1.8. But figured out that I do not need to change the source and target versions in the pom.xml. Just changed the JAVA_HOME from "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31" to "C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk1.8.0_202" and the build and war generation happens as it was happening with Java6.